# When trying to push a json object, a previously defined variable name is being processed literally. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, json

`onLoadLang` is a variable declared as "en_us" earlier in the code.

when I try to push using the following:

```
UdfHeaderFields["translations"].push({ onLoadLang: [{ "H1": "English" }, { "H2": "English" }, { "H3": "English" }, { "H4": "English" }, { "H5": "English" }] });
```

The `onLoadLang` portion gets pushed as `"onLoadLang"` and not `"en_us"`

[image]

Here is what it looks like after the step over.

[image]

I have tried surrounding it with various char types to no avail.

Comment: Show the actual code, not an image of it.

Comment: Well to the parser it is a key "onLoadLang", it has no clue you are referring to it as a variable. See the duplicate on how to set it as a varaible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put square brackets around the variable name if you don't want it to be treated as a literal.  Consider this working code example:

```js
let x = "en_us"
let y = []
y.push( { x: "the key is x" } )
y.push( { [x]: "the key is en_us" } )
console.log(y)
```

Comment: This worked. I tried everything except square brackets. /facepalm